# Can I process multiple SQS messages in parallel by launching multiple EC2 instances which poll the queue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

I have an SQS queue which contains messages that need not be consumed in order. This queue is mostly for decoupling purpose. I have 2 EC2 hosts that I would want to poll this queue. The processing of each message takes time. While one of my EC2 instance is processing a message, can my other EC2 poll the next message from the queue?

If this cannot be done, then is using an SQS an incorrect approach here? Should I instead configure an autoscaling group of EC2 instances and load balance the incoming requests among the EC2 instances?

Comment: This is the perfect use-case for Amazon SQS. If the EC2 instance has multiple CPUs, you could even run multiple programs ("workers") on a single EC2 instance, with each worker pulling its own messages from the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, when a instance grabs the message it is put in " Messages in flight" status. this is not available to other instances polling the queue.

Efectly reserving that message for that consumer.

more info here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/features-capabilities.html